# Special characters Scanner Java

Tags: java, special-characters, java.util.scanner

How can you read special characters from a file with the java Scanner class? I tried mentioning an enconding but it doesn't work.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"), "utf-8");
Scanner lineScanner = null;
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    lineScanner = new Scanner(scanner.nextLine());
    lineScanner.useDelimiter(";");
    String article = lineScanner.next();
    // and so on...
}
// Close the scanners
```

What I am trying to read is a line like this:

```
"la;leçon;de les;lesòn"
```

Comment: Your line can be read by Scanner without charset!! Have you tried it?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? The problem can also be in how you display the data that was read.

Comment: I use a while condition to check if the scanner has next line. It doesn't even go into the while. 
My next lines are:

Scanner lineScanner = null;

while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
      lineScanner = new Scanner(scanner.nextLine());
      lineScanner.useDelimiter(";");
      String article = lineScanner.next();
...
//and so on
}
//Close the scanners

Comment: The whole code works if I don't use any special characters

Comment: I solved my problem: the encoding was wrong. It should be: iso-8859-1

Comment: Make sure to post & accept an answer to your question, explaining exactly what you did to solve the problem and why there was one to begin with. That might help other people having the same issue.

Comment: I wonder, I have used an online compiler and executed your code providing your example string instead of the `File` object and without charset. I printed the result and it displayed fine. I rejoin @TAsk, did you actually try without providing any charset?

Comment: Yes I did, and it didn't work, that's why I thought it might be because of the special characters, so I removed them and it worked (but that's not a good solution).

Answer (score 0):

The character encoding is not right. It should be iso-8859-1 for french.